# Java regualr expression matches and puts to an array doesn't work

Tags: java, regex, arraylist

I have a list (AllHdList) like this

```
1300000
1300001
1300002
1300006
1300008
1300010
1300011
1300012
1300013
1300014
1300015
1300016
1300017
1300018
1300019
1300050
1300051
1300052
1300053
1300054
1300055
1300056
1300057
1300058
1300059
1300190
1300191
1300192
1300193
1300194
1300195
1300196
1300197
1300198
1300199
```

and as the regular expression like `^130019.|^130005.`, the following items should be matched:

`System.out.println( p2 +"--"+ AllHdList.get(i) + "->" + m2.find());`

```
^130019.|^130005.--1300000->false
^130019.|^130005.--1300001->false
^130019.|^130005.--1300002->false
^130019.|^130005.--1300006->false
^130019.|^130005.--1300008->false
^130019.|^130005.--1300010->false
^130019.|^130005.--1300011->false
^130019.|^130005.--1300012->false
^130019.|^130005.--1300013->false
^130019.|^130005.--1300014->false
^130019.|^130005.--1300015->false
^130019.|^130005.--1300016->false
^130019.|^130005.--1300017->false
^130019.|^130005.--1300018->false
^130019.|^130005.--1300019->false
^130019.|^130005.--1300050->true
^130019.|^130005.--1300051->true
^130019.|^130005.--1300052->true
^130019.|^130005.--1300053->true
^130019.|^130005.--1300054->true
^130019.|^130005.--1300055->true
^130019.|^130005.--1300056->true
^130019.|^130005.--1300057->true
^130019.|^130005.--1300058->true
^130019.|^130005.--1300059->true
^130019.|^130005.--1300190->true
^130019.|^130005.--1300191->true
^130019.|^130005.--1300192->true
^130019.|^130005.--1300193->true
^130019.|^130005.--1300194->true
^130019.|^130005.--1300195->true
^130019.|^130005.--1300196->true
^130019.|^130005.--1300197->true
^130019.|^130005.--1300198->true
^130019.|^130005.--1300199->true
```

I am trying to put those that are not matched to an array by using the code here, but my code doesn't work:

```
public static void get7HdQh(List<String> AllHdList){

        List <String> tempList  = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i=0; i<AllHdList.size(); i++){

                Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("^130019.|^130005.");
                Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(AllHdList.get(i));


                if (!m2.find()) {
                    tempList.add(AllHdList.get(i));
                }

        } 
    System.out.println( tempList );        
 }
```

Comment: Where is tempList defined?  What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I added templist in this method.  result of tempList is all elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too much code. Use `String#matches()` instead:

```
List <String> tempList  = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String s : AllHdList)
    if (!s.matches("130019.|130005."))
        tempList.add(s);
```

Or the entire method in 1 line with java 8:

```
public static void get7HdQh(List<String> list) {
    list.stream().filter(s -> !s.matches("130019.|130005.")).foreach(System.out::println);
}
```

or if you actually want to collect them:

```
List<String> tempList = list.stream().filter(s -> !s.matches("130019.|130005.")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note how (for all java versions) you don't need the anchor `"^"` in your regex - it's implied, because `matches()` must match the *whole* string to be true.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the first code and It didn't work. And then I changed expression to ("130019.|130005.")), it works

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this,

```
String[] value = {"1300199", "1300058", "1300013","1300014"};
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String i: value)
{
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^(?:130019|130005).").matcher(i);
if(!m.find())
{
    list.add(i);
}
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[1300013, 1300014]
```